# What is the difference between install docker with python-pip and with yum?

Tags: docker, pip

What is the difference between install docker with python-pip and with yum ? thank you

Answer (score 2):

**1:** `pip` is the package installer for `Python client API`. You can use pip to install packages from the Python Package Index. By this you will install a Docker client library that will interact with Docker. For this to work Docker has to be installed already.

**2:** `YUM` is the primary package management tool for installing, updating, removing, and managing software packages in RedHat Operating system. Like `Brew` for `MacOS`, `apt` for `Ubuntu`.

Comment: @N. Liraj - Let me know if my question helps you.